# "imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:" "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL" key strange behavior in info dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In "`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`" the info dictionary sometimes doesn't have the key "`UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`". Sometimes it does have. I tried cleaning the targets but that didn't help. Also, the workflow is always the same: I follow the same steps and choose the same video file from library. Sometime info dictionary has   "`UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`" key in it and sometime   "`UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`" is absent in the info dictionary itself for the same file. Could not understand it. Can somebody help ?

This is my `NSLog` of info dictionary when i select video/movie from photos library :

```
info dict = {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=1000000466&ext=MOV";
}
```

Comment: This happens on an iPhone 4 with 2GB free space, iOS 6.1, for a video with +2 minutes. It won't happen for an iPhone 5 with 600MB of free space, for a video with the same length.

I thought it could be related with the lack of free space on the device to save the temporary compressed video, but this doesn't add up.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? The upvoted answer doesn't even seem to understand the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{ 
    NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You Select a image Please select Movie" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [myAlertView show];

        [myAlertView release];

    }

    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){

        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        mAppDelegate.uploadType = @"Video";

        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

        [infoDict setValue:webData forKey:@"VideoUrl"];

        [infoDict setValue:[[mAppDelegate.userInfoArray objectAtIndex:1]valueForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];

        [[WakeUpParsing sharedInstance] assignSender:self];

        [[WakeUpParsing sharedInstance] startParsingForVedioUploade:infoDict];

    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [infoDict release];

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker

{

    // Dismiss the image selection and close the program
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: But it shows UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie"; in my log. So it is confirmed that it is movie

Comment: It can't happen if your media type is mov, then its url also there

Answer (score 0):

It happen when your account Video save on iCloud. When you choose video it will temporarily download from icloud and show to you so  UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL will don't appear.